# How to interpret Intention To Treat (ITT) effect when effect is negative?

Tags: econometrics, instrumental-variables, treatment-effect

In ITT models like: $Y_i=\delta_0 + \delta_1Z_i + \nu_i$ where $Z_i$ represents assignment to treatment,

the treatment coefficient $\delta_1$ systematically under-estimates the true effect of the treatment. Depending on the compliance rate, $\delta_1$ is going to be somewhere between zero and an unbiased estimator of the true treatment effect.

But what about if the treatment negatively affects $Y_i$ ?

If $\delta_1 = -.5$, is the true effect of the treatment somewhere between -.5 and 0, lower than -.5, or greater than -.5 (potentially surpassing 0)?

Comment: ITT is intention-to-treat?

Comment: yes intention-to-treat

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this model, but underestimating an effect would seem to make it smaller in magnitude, so it feels like it would be less than -.5 (i.e. more negative). That would make $true < \delta_1 < 0$.

Comment: Look up the formula for the Wald estimator. It gives a lot of intuition in this setting.

Answer (score -1):

The intention to treat (in the case with no covariates) is equal to the product of the treatment effect and the compliance rate. If the treatment effect is negative, this is still true. Because the compliance rate is between 0 and 1, if the intention to treat is equal to $-.5$, the treatment effect will be lower than $-.5$ (i.e. more negative than $-.5$).